# Java reflection : what modifying at runtime means?

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

I'm learining Java reflection API. I have read a lot, use `java.lang.reflect` package.
But there is still something I don't understand : the idea that with introspection, you can modify objects at runtime.

Basically you do not need introspection/reflection to do that. With a simple setter() method, you can also modify your object at runtime. What's the difference between using simple setters or using reflection ? In both cases you can achieve the same result.

Comment: Where does your “idea that with introspection, you can modify objects at runtime” come from? Which source did say it in such a way that you got the feeling that modifying objects via Reflection was something different than modifying objects without?

Answer (score 2):

With reflection you can instantiate objects and call methods that you didn't know about at compile time.

Imagine you had a text file that contained the name of a class. You can use reflection to load and instantiate that class, even if that file didn't exist when your program was compiled.

Similarly, you can use it to build things like generic configuration systems where you create objects and set properties based on some configuration files instead of using hard-coded calls (Spring is one way this can go).

Comment: agree with that and understood that part. But you could also use values from client input (from a form for example) to build object. If a client clicks on a button, object A will be created with values from the form. If client clicks another button, in that case object B will be created. So even without using reflection, you can still have dynamic objects that cannot be known at compile time

Comment: What you are describing is to pick from a range of known options based on user input. Your code will have to mention each of the viable options somewhere. What I'm describing is the user input picking a previously unknown option. The user might, for example, enter a class name of a class that is never mentioned anywhere in your code.